# Failed to declare queue: springCloudBus.anonymous

Tags: mongodb, rabbitmq, yaml

> I used RabbitMq in my project .In my point of view I declare all the
> things required for this project. But I don't know where I miss the
> thing that create error here I provide all the details that I used in
> my project.

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'springCloudBus.anonymous.9XKB94ZlSFatq7c5KyTIxw' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:517) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:341) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:182) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:114) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:739) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:666) ~[amqp-client-5.12.0.jar:5.12.0]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

> bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
    vault:
      host: localhost
      port: 8288
      scheme: http
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: s.atm1jyRmex8zm7HgGjyKRB7H
      application-name: product-service

  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest

  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/microservice-realm




  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/product-service
  application:
    name: PRODUCT-SERVICE


management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

> application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/product-service

  application:
    name: PRODUCT-SERVICE


eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}

server:
  port: 0
```

> gradlke.kt

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.20"
}

group = "com.main"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

extra["springCloudVersion"] = "2020.0.3"

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config:3.0.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.4.6")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp:3.0.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-client:3.0.1")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.0.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${property("springCloudVersion")}")
    }
}



tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> I get this type of error   : Failed to declare queue:
> springCloudBus.anonymous.9XKB94ZlSFatq7c5KyTIxw